# Synchrotron radiation and special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, elementary-particles, synchrotron-radiation

My questions below are for all those who assume the point-like electron of special relativity, that strange entity with no inner structure (!), but with *intrinsic* (?) rest energy, magnetic moment and spin.

1. As inside the electromagnetic cavities in synchrotron the free electrons are accelerated by taking over in flight the energy of the field particles of electromagnetic interaction, the photons, can these electrons take over the energy of the accelerating particles without absorbing them, given that special relativity interdicts such absorptions by free electrons?
2. As it is experimentally established for a very long time, the electrons accelerated in electromagnetic field convert integrally the energy $eV$ received by them from the field into their kinetic energy $E_k$, $eV = E_k$. But then, what is the source of the energy of synchrotron radiation emitted outside by electrons during their electromagnetic acceleration, as long as in special relativity the total energy of the point-like electrons is the sum of only two terms, their kinetic energy $E_k$ and their unchangeable *intrinsic* rest energy $E_0 = m_0c^2$?
3. Since the point-like electron has an *intrinsic* spin $h/4π$, and the point-like photon an *intrinsic* spin $h/2π$, how is the fundamental law of angular momentum conservation observed at any elementary act of photon emission or photon absorption?
4. As it is experimentally noticed, synchrotron radiation emitted by the electrons inside the accelerating electromagnetic cavities is entirely different from that emitted by them after leaving these cavities: inside the cavities, where the radiating electrons move in a straight line, they emit photons only “forward” and strictly under emission angles $β = arccos(v/c)$ as against their motion direction, and in addition the emitted photons have a degree of circular polarization directly proportional to their velocity ratios $(v/c)$, but when their photon emission extends a very short time even after leaving the electromagnetic cavities, when the radiating electrons begin instantaneously to move on a circular trajectory due to the Lorentz force, they emit photons in all directions in their orbital plane, both “forward” and “back”, and the radiated photons are 100 % linearly polarized.
   Well, can special relativity explain these essential differences, and how is the fundamental law of conservation of momentum observed in each variant?

Comment: An electron is a quantum number of a quantum field. Why does a quantum number have to have an inner structure? The energy is that of the quantum state and it belongs to the entire field, not to the specific state. As a general comment, you are asking all the wrong questions from the wrong theory. Special relativity can't tell you any more about quantum field theory than Newtonian mechanics call tell you about the chemistry of Jupiter's core. What it can tell is how Jupiter's gravity affects the rest of the solar system, though, and that's why its important. You need to learn ALL the tools.

Comment: @CuriousOne - My post is entitled “Synchrotron radiation and special relativity”, and not “Synchrotron radiation and quantum physics”. I see your belief in a quantum physics able to explain everything in microcosm, still genuine special relativity has nothing to do with quantum theory. Believe Einstein in this regard. As for the tools recommended by you, sorry, but the rotten foundations of quantum physics are enough for me.

Comment: I can see that you are not interested in actual understanding of physics, so I will leave you alone now. Have a nice day.

Comment: @CuriousOne Regret, but how could I learn a quantum physics appeared just because of a terrible mistake of the beginnings, a Planck’s constant twice higher than its real value? Beyond doubt, this error will be inevitably recognized once, sooner or later, despite the interested reluctance of those who have much to lose, even if they are many and very important in physicists’ community.

Comment: It took you that long to come back with a desperate comment like that? :-)

Answer (score 2):

1. You seem to think of electrons and photons as point particles from relativistic mechanics that have rectilinear trajectory until they collide. This is only one of many different ways to give meaning to these two words. Within this view, if an electron collides with a photon, and if conservation of energy and momentum is assumed, the resulting state after the collision can be calculated and is such that the electron and the photon move with altered velocities and are getting away from each other. The new velocities may be such that the electron has gained energy from the photon or that it has given some energy to the photon or that no energy, only momentum has been transferred. It all depends on the initial energy and momenta of the particles.

This picture of EM interaction as being transferred by point photons gives good results only for some specific questions such as the Compton scattering, but is not very powerful generally. Many things such as interference cannot be explained by it. There is much more succesfull theory -  Maxwell equations + the Lorentz force formula (which however still cannot explain everything).

2. It is not true that all the energy gained from the power grid in the cavity goes into kinetic energy of the electrons inside. The process of acceleration is accompanied by EM radiation that carries energy. So the natural description of the energy flux during the acceleration is that part of the energy from the power grid goes to increased kinetic energy of the electrons, while part of it remains in the form of EM energy, gets away from the electrons and is absorbed in the surrounding equipment (the walls making up the vacuum tube, the magnets, the air in the lab etc.)
3. I'll pass on this one.
4. Yes, the radiation of charged particles can be explained by relativistic EM theory of charged particles (with EM field and without photons). This is different theory than the above mentioned buckshot photon theory. The momentum is conserved in the sense that all changes of momentum are continuous and whatever momentum is lost from some region can be understood as lost through the boundary surface. This is bit advanced mathematically for a beginner. First try to learn the Maxwell equations, then search for EM energy and momentum density, the stress energy tensor and the conservation laws.

Comment: I expect strictly to the point answers to my questions concerning special relativity itself, and not all kinds of comments beside them (your first answer is a little masterpiece in this sense), so that your third answer remains the only worthy to be considered. However, two remarks:
1. Since Maxwell’s electromagnetic waves are by definition strictly transversal, his theory has been entirely invalidated by longitudinal electromagnetic radiation emitted by fast particles, including synchrotron radiation emitted inside electromagnetic cavities. Let Maxwell’s theory rest in peace!

Comment: 2. Your second answer affirms an amazing ad hoc partition of the energy $eV$ received by accelerated electrons from their accelerating electromagnetic field: one part converted by them into kinetic energy until they reach a determined velocity $v$, another radiated outside, but only after they reach their final velocity $v$, which all properties of their synchrotron radiation emitted inside electromagnetic cavities depend on. Have you some unpublished data about such an unheard taking over of the energy $eV$ in two distinct stages and with different uses of the two distinct parts?

Comment: Re 1. I did now mention any Maxwell's electromagnetic waves, so your comment is out of context and I have no idea why you wrote it. In my answer I describe what happens to energy during the passage of electrons through the acceleration cavity. Re 2. The partition of energy into kinetic energy of electrons and EM energy is customary, I see no reason to call it ad hoc. In EM theory, radiation does not occur after electrons reach some velocity, it happens whenever they move with non-zero acceleration, which is the case all the time they move in circles.

Comment: Further information on the principle of the accelerator  should be possible to find in Jackson's and Schwinger's textbook on EM theory.